# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property valid of #<ReduxForm> which has only a getter

Tags: redux-form

I am trying to insert redux-form into my project, but I am getting this error. Does anybody has idea what is the problem.

What I concluded so far is that when I add following piece of code, it starts returning me this error - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property valid of # which has only a getter".

```
LoginForm = reduxForm({
  // a unique name for the form
  form: 'login',
})(LoginForm);
```

Comment: were you able to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `react-hot-loader` from webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I realized the problem was somewhere in configuration. More particularly, next code somehow produced not compatible component:

```
LoginForm = reduxForm({
  // a unique name for the form
  form: 'login',
})(LoginForm);
```

One of package.json modules was not compatible with react-form. Most probably react-hot-loader. Anyway, I created new project based on Facebook's create-react-app and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to upgrade the `react-hot-loader` to v3 which is currently in beta.

```
yarn add --dev react-hot-loader@3.0.0-beta.7
```

Or with npm

```
npm install --save-dev react-hot-loader@3.0.0-beta.7
```

And then update your webpack loaders section to `react-hot-loader/webpack`

More about this on the [redux-form GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1010#issuecomment-266934194)